# Space in div using z-index

Tags: css, image, html, styles

```
    .games_box
    {
    width:575px;
    margin:8px auto;
    background:#f8f7f7;
    padding:8px;
    border-bottom:#000000 1px dotted;
    }

 <div class="games_box">
<a href='#'>
<img src='$host_name/staff/game-$row[0].gif' width='78' height='75'  alt='games' />
    <div id='staff' style='position:relative; top:-50px;z-index:1; left:29px'>
<img src='images/staff_picks.png' alt='staffpick' width='50' height='51' /></div>
</a>
</div>
```

I put staff div.. the games-box div is large..
i use 'clear:both'.. but no use..

1 st

[image]

2 nd

place staff pick image

[image: place staff pick image]

3 rd

finally, z-index used staffpick image, under image more space

[image]

Comment: can you explain what exactly do you need or show us the fiddle or show the screenshot....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can give parent position relative and child give absolute as like this

**Css**

```
.games_box
    {
    width:575px;
    margin:8px auto;
    background:#f8f7f7;
    padding:8px;
    border-bottom:#000000 1px dotted;
    position:relative;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="games_box">
<a href='#'>
<img src='$host_name/staff/game-$row[0].gif' width='78' height='75'  alt='games' />
    <div id='staff' style='position:absolute; top:-5px;z-index:1; left:29px'>
<img src='images/staff_picks.png' alt='staffpick' width='50' height='51' /></div>
</a>
</div>
```

Live Demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/grE5A/

Comment: I have changed css and staff div style.. the staff pick is not visible. i need only base image over staff pick image..

Comment: Your code and i set staff div width,height.. its worked..  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To 'suck up the space' you can use `margin-top:-50px;` or use `position:absolute` like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/grE5A/2/.

Notice I've given the `<a>` tag the relative position as it is the 'parent' that #staff needs to be positioned absolutely in.

The reason you had the space under the image is because `position:relative; top:-50px` moves the staff pick up relative to it's original position, but the parent still behaves like the element is in its original position. (Z-index has no effect what you are trying to do.)